# Button overlapping input 100% when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button expand fully across an input element. I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried using absolute:position; and that didn't seem to work and I have tried a few other methods that seemed to be more complicated then what I probably needed and did not work for the most part

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```css
  .s-btn {width:40px;height:40px;}
  
  .expand > span {display:none;}  
  .expand:hover > span {display:inline-block;}
  .expand:hover {width:100%;}
  
  .transition {
    /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    transition: All 0.5s ease;  
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Help</h2>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Test Modal for Help Button</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container" style="overflow:hidden;padding:50px 0;">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-hover-red w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <form class="w3-container" style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">          
          <!-- Trouble Area: -->
          <button class="w3-button expand s-btn transition w3-deep-purple"><span>What's my company code</span>?</button>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Company Code">
          <!-- END: -->
          <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple w3-padding">Submit</button>     
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the button expands to 100% like i'm looking for but I want to have it expand on top of the input field.

Below is an example of how I would like it to look but of course implement the full width of the input field.

```css
<style>
  .s-btn {width:40px;height:40px;}
  
  .expand > span {display:none;}  
  .expand:hover > span {display:inline-block;}
  .expand:hover {width:250px;}
  
  .transition {
    /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    transition: All 0.5s ease;  
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Help</h2>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Test Modal for Help Button</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container" style="overflow:hidden;padding:50px 0;">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-hover-red w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <form class="w3-container" style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">          
          <div class="w3-row w3-section">
            <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px;"><button class="w3-button expand s-btn transition w3-deep-purple"><span>What's my company code</span>?</button></div>
            <div class="w3-rest">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Company Code">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple w3-padding">Submit</button>     
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this the effect you're looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLpoXa

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much @MichaelCoker . How do I make it to where the placeholder text doesnt appear above the button, or is that just a chrome thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely position the button to the left of the `input`, and trigger the width change on `:hover` and it will expand over the `input`

```css
.s-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.s-btn + .w3-input {
  margin-left: 45px;
  width: auto;
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
}

.w3-container {
  position: relative;
}

.expand > span {
  display: none;
}
.expand:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.expand:hover {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.transition {
  /*Transition*/
  -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  transition: All 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Help</h2>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Test Modal for Help Button</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container" style="overflow:hidden;padding:50px 0;">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-hover-red w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <form class="w3-container" style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">          
          <!-- Trouble Area: -->
          <button class="w3-button expand s-btn transition w3-deep-purple"><span>What's my company code</span>?</button>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Company Code">
          <!-- END: -->
          <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple w3-padding">Submit</button>     
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll accept it in 3 mins, I guess there is a wait time. If you didnt see my message from earlier "How do I make it to where the placeholder text doesnt appear above the button, or is that just a chrome thing?"

Comment: Sweet, i tried z-index earlier and it didnt work for some reason. You the man though, thanks a ton

Comment: @RickSibley you bet :)